# How to find Pr(A,B,C)? (Probability of Intersection of three circles)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Can someone please help to find the intersection of three circles given following conditions:
$$n|A\cup B\cup C|=750$$
$$|A|=412$$
$$|B|=321$$
$$|C|=338$$
$$|A\cap B|=121$$
$$|A\cap C|=115$$
$$|B\cap C|=105$$
All three events are basically three intersecting circles.
So far I got this:
$ P(A∩B∩C)=P(A)P(B│A)P(C│A,B)$ 
Calculating it one at a time I come to:
$$P(A)=219/750=0.2920$$
$$P(B│A)=P(A∩B)/P(A) =121/412=0.2937$$
$$P(C│A,B)=P(C│A)∩P(C│B)=P(C∩A)/P(A) ∩P(C∩B)/(P(B))$$
And this is where I'm stuck.

Using Chain Rule I have this expression: $P(A∩B∩C)=P(C│A∩B)*P(B│A)*P(A)$ 
But I can't see how to calculate $P(C│A,B)$. 
Can some one please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $n=|P(A\cup B\cup C)|$ (since you didn't specify), apply the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

$$750=(412+321+338)-(121+115+105)+P(A\cap B\cap C)$$
It follows that $P(A\cap B\cap C) = 20$.

Comment: Oh... this makes sense. Just checked the wording of the question, and this seems to be the case. Thank you. I've updated my question.
But then when would I use the chain rule, like I tried?

Answer (score 4):

An answer without using the inclusion exclusion principle.

[image]